# Common values in a Python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code that will return common values from a dictionary based on a list of words. 
Example:

```
inp = ['here','now']
dict = {'here':{1,2,3}, 'now':{2,3}, 'stop':{1, 3}}

for val in inp.intersection(D):
    lst = D[val]

print(sorted(lst))

output: [2, 3]
```

The input inp may contain any one or all of the above words, and I want to know what values they have in common. I just cannot seem to figure out how to do that. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `D` ? do you mean your `dict` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes.. I apologize. In my code dict is D I forgot to change it when I did a copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to just count them all, and then make a dict of the values that are equal to the number of sets you intersected.

To accomplish the first part, we do something like this:

```
answer = {}
for word in inp:
  for itm in word:
    if itm in answer:
      answer[itm] += 1
    else:
      answer[itm] = 1
```

To accomplish the second part, we just have to iterate over `answer` and build an array like so:

```
answerArr = []
for i in answer:
  if (answer[i] == len(inp)):
    answerArr.append(i)
```

Comment: Yes! just as I saw that you answered my question (which I very much appreciate, thank you) I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not certain that i understood your question perfectly but i think this is what you meant albeit in a very simple way:

```
inp = ['here','now']
dict = {'here':{1,2,3}, 'now':{2,3}, 'stop':{1, 3}}

output = []

for item in inp:
    output.append(dict[item])

for item in output:
    occurances = output.count(item)
    if occurances <= 1:
        output.remove(item)

print(output)
```

This should output the items from the dict which occurs in more than one input. If you want it to be common for all of the inputs just change the <= 1 to be the number of inputs given.